# PowerShell question with sorting and piping

Tags: powershell, syntax, select-object

Hello I am using PowerShell Version 5
I am running a command and it is working but the narrowed search is not returning results.

```
Get-EventLog System -Newest 5 | where {$_.eventID -eq 1074}
```

So I thought oh I only want to see the last 5 objects that match my filter.  It runs but returns no result because in the event log there is no eventID 1074 in the last 5 entries.  So I just need to move that parameter to the end.  No luck

```
Get-EventLog System | where {$_.eventID -eq 1074} | -newest 5

-newest : The term '-newest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:53
+ Get-EventLog System | where {$_.eventID -eq 1074} | -newest 5
+                                                     ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-newest:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

So, positioning the `-newest` after the pipe moves the parameter into a position I think where it is not understood.

Any one have some advice to how I can approach thinking about this that will help me out in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To limit your *filtered* results to at most 5 events, you must use `Select-Object -First 5` in a final pipeline segment:

```
Get-EventLog System | Where-Object { $_.eventID -eq 1074 } | Select-Object -First 5
```

`-Newest <n>` is a parameter that is specific to `Get-EventLog`, and it *unconditionally* returns the first `<n>` entries, irrespective of their content.

There is no [*common parameter* across cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters) that offers similar functionality, but there's the generic [`Select-Object` *cmdlet*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) that allows selecting up to `<n>` objects from whatever its input is via `-First <n>`.

Answer (score 2):

here's a likely faster way to get the info you seem to want. it uses `Get-WinEvent` instead of `Get-EventLog` and also uses the `-FilterHashtable` parameter to let the event system do some of the filtering.

```
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

$FilterHash = @{
    Logname = 'System'
    ID = 1074
    StartTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-20)
    }
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $FilterHash -MaxEvents 20
```

this is *usually* noticeably faster than using `Get-EventLog`. [*grin*]

here's an article on the ideas ...

Use FilterHashTable to Filter Event Log with PowerShell – Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog
— https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/06/03/use-filterhashtable-to-filter-event-log-with-powershell/

Comment: It takes about 1.5 seconds to pull that info from a remote machine in my environment using get-WinEvent.  It takes about 3 mins to pull the same info using get-EventLog.

I definitely will look into get-WinEvent more.  Thank you for the tip and the reference material for further study.

Comment: @Brian - you are quite welcome! glad to have helped ... [*grin*]